# Excel Cells Formatting with Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel

I am just trying to put together some Visual Basic lines for an Excel File so when the content of the cells of a particular column meet a specific comparison condition the color of the corresponding row will take a predefined color. Here is some testing code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  If ActiveCell = "OK" Then
    Range("A13:E13").Select
    With Selection.Interior
     .ColorIndex = 4
     .Pattern = xlSolid
   End With
End If
End Sub
```

Apparently, this has to function for all the sheet not just for 13. Also, the problem is that the above does't work with **ActiveCell**. Is there a more effective way to try that? Some help please!

Comment: Is it not Possible to do that with Conditional Format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  If ActiveCell.Value = "OK" Then
     'Here ActiveCell is any cell that is active,
     'but you say, that you want to test the cells of
     'a particular column, in that case you could use
     'Opt 01:
     'If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then 'Here you are asking for the column
                                    'for the ActiveCell
                                    ' use a nested if
     'If ActiveCell.Value = "OK" Then ' here if the activecell is in the
                                      ' right column and is with the right
                                      'value, you get the rows colored
    'Range("A13:E13").Select 'Well you are using this... but you say
                             'that you want to color the row of the corresponding cell
                             'in that case you can use this:
    Dim r
    Dim rng As Range

    r = ActiveCell.Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 20)) 'you store inside rng the cells:
                                               'from column 1 = A, Row x
                                               'to column 20 = T, row x
                                               ' where x is the row of the activecell
                                               'you can change the column as you need
    With rng.Interior 'here you can use rng instead selection
                      'and you affect the cells without selecting them.
     .ColorIndex = 4
     .Pattern = xlSolid
   End With
End If
End Sub
```

Or you can use a conditional formating...

Where you evaluate the contents of cells of the column you need. I think this a better aproach for whay you'r saying.

[image]

Comment: It work great man, impeccably! I think the same, that Conditional Formatting make this stuff much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this;

```
 If ActiveCell = "OK" Then
```

with this;

```
 If ActiveCell.value = "OK" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to avoid `select` or `active*` if not really needed. They can be avoided most of the time and slow down your code.
So instead of `Range("A13:E13").Select` folowed by `selection.interior´ go for
´Range("A13:E13").Interior´.

You want to check for the value of the cell. So it is ´activecell.value´not only activecell. Even better ´worksheets(x).cells(y, z).value´ or ´worksheets(x).range("yz").value´